# Intent filter with navigation component to Receiving image data from other app

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, intentfilter, android-deep-link

My Android application uses the navigation component to navigate between fragments.

And the project only has a single Activity and all the others are fragments.

My application is a social media application. I want to share an image from my phone gallery with my application. When a user clicks the share button on the gallery, my application wants to show in the sharing dialogue.

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

I have used this intent filter on my main activity, and then the share dialogue displays my app.

But my requirement is, I want to get that image on my fragment. How to use this intent filter on my fragment.

Can I use the deep-link for that? but what value will give on the uri section?.

```
<deepLink
            app:uri="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
            app:action="android.intent.action.SEND"
            app:mimeType="image/*"
            />
```

I tried this. but not working.

In short, I want to receive the data (image) in my fragment. How can I achieve this using the Navigation component?

Answer (score 0):

To explain why it's not working for you, let's examine this piece of code,

```
            app:uri="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
            app:action="android.intent.action.SEND"
            app:mimeType="image/*"/>
```

**app:uri** attribute requires a scheme and a host e.g., **https://example.com** (it could be any made up uri like **myapp://example.com**) , but you are passing a category string to it.
To fix this, just pass "myapp://example.com" or any made up uri you can think of. That will work. Now, the important bit - you must add **deeplink** tag to the fragment which receives the image. Now, your code will work, however, if your application is already running, it will not receive the image from shared intent. For that, you need to override **onNewIntent** method in you activity and call `NavController.handleDeepLink(intent)`, you have to pass the intent received in **onNewIntent** method to it, followed by a call to **super.onNewIntent()**. Now, your app can receive image from any application that can share it, whether your application is already running, or started by the intent itself.